# How to drag and drop the content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[`Here`](https://jsfiddle.net/yyycbthy/) is the fiddle.
I tried to drag and drop the hello into div tag.. It was successful. Now how can I drop the same hello into another div tag. If the drop targets are more than one how can we drop over the targets?

Comment: You should still share the relevant part of your code here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yyycbthy/1/

Once analyse code in this fiddle.If i had one more div,to drop the hello to taht second div i need to keep tat div id into drop event.but if i have multiple ,more than 3,4 then how can i use the drop event

Comment: Accept my edit, it will fix the link on your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of targeting drop area with `id` target it with `classname`. That will take care of everything. So below will be the changes:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var data1;
 $(".draggable").bind('drag',function(event)
 { 
  data1=event.target.id; 
 });
 $(".droppable").on("dragover",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
 });
 $(".droppable").on("dragleave",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
 });
 $(".droppable").on("drop",function(event)
 {
  event.preventDefault();
  var d=document.getElementById(data1).innerHTML;
  event.target.innerHTML=event.target.innerHTML+d;
 });
});
```

```css
.droppable {width:200px;height:auto;padding:5px;border:2px solid #915C83;min-height: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="droppable" name="ans"></div>
<div id="div2" class="droppable" name="ans"></div>
<div id="div3" class="droppable" name="ans"></div>
<div id="div4" class="droppable" name="ans"></div>
<div class="draggable" draggable="true" id="drag1">Hello</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yyycbthy/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind the events with class not as per DIV id. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/yyycbthy/2/). I think this what you want!

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" class="droppable" name="ans"></div>
<div id="div2" class="droppable" name="ans"></div>
<div class="draggable" draggable="true" id="drag1">Hello</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {width:200px;height:auto;padding:5px;border:2px solid #915C83;min-height: 15px;}
#div2 {width:200px;height:auto;padding:5px;border:2px solid #915C83;min-height: 15px;}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
                var data1;
                $(".draggable").bind('drag',function(event)
                    { 
                        data1=event.target.id; 
                    });
                $(".droppable").on("dragover",function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    });
                $(".droppable").on("dragleave",function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();

                    });
                $(".droppable").on("drop",function(event)
                    {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var d=document.getElementById(data1).innerHTML;
                        event.target.innerHTML=event.target.innerHTML+d;
                    });
        });
```